# Definition of symplectic map

Tags: symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I just started reading on symplectic integrator of Hamiltonian system for my physics project, I don't quite understand some of the basic definitions here(see https://na.uni-tuebingen.de/~lubich/chap6.pdf)

> Definition 2.1. A linear mapping A : $R^{2d}$ → $R^{2d}$ is called symplectic if $A^{T}JA = J$ or, equivalently, if ω(Aξ, Aη) = ω(ξ, η) for all ξ, η ∈ $R^{2d}$.

where he defined $\omega$ to be the area between vectoors ξ and η. I understand the second definition that says a symplectic linear map preserves the area between any two vectors but how are these two definitions equivalent?

And the author gave a definition for a (non-linear)differentiable map:

> Definition 2.2. A differentiable map g : U → $R^{2d}$
>   (where U ⊂ $R^{2d}$ is an open set) is called symplectic if the Jacobian matrix g'(p, q) is everywhere symplectic, i.e., if
>   $g'(p, q)^{T}Jg'(p, q) = J$ or ω(g'(p, q)ξ, g'(p, q)η) = ω(ξ, η).

Can someone give me a intuition that why we define symplectic differentiable map like this followed from Definition 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since $\omega(\xi,\eta) = \xi^t J \eta,$ we have $\omega(A\xi,A\eta) = \omega(\xi,\eta)$ iff $\xi^t (A^t J A) \eta = (A\xi)^t J (A\eta) = \xi^t J \eta$ iff the bilinear forms $\omega$ and $\omega'(\xi,\eta) := \xi^t (A^t J A) \eta$ coincide iff their corresponding matrices (namely $J$ and $A^t J A$, respectively) coincide. (Recall that on any $n$-dimensional vector space with a specified basis (here it's $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ with the standard basis) there is an isomorphism between the space of $(n\times n)$-matrices and the space of bilinear forms given by $A \mapsto ((v,w) \mapsto [v]^t A [w])$ (where the brackets denote the coordinates in the given basis).)

> Can someone give me a intuition that why we define symplectic differentiable map like this followed from Definition 2.1?

The most straightforward way to generalize the definition to differentiable maps is to work locally: at any point, the derivative there is a linear map beween $2d$-dimensional vector spaces, so it makes sense to say whether or not it is symplectic. So you can think of such a symplectic differentiable mapping as a map which preserves the symplectic form near every point.

Does that help?

Comment: it certainly helped. I didn't realize $\omega$  can be written as $ξ^{t}Jη$, now it's much clear. However I didn't quite follow the part you said about the isomorphism and I don't know why that's import in showing the equivalence.

Comment: @Anonymous The crux of what I'm saying is that, once we fixed a basis once and for all for our vector space, a matrix gives rise to a unique bilinear form on the space, and this is a bijective correspondence. So two matrices are equal exactly when their corresponding bilinear forms are equal (this means that they take the same values on all pairs of vectors). Here the matrix $J$ corresponds to the form $\omega$ and the matrix $A^t J A$ corresponds to the form $\omega';$ then to say that $\omega = \omega'$ is equivalent to saying that $J = A^t J A.$

Comment: And for the second part, I think I kinda understand now, the derivative is linear map and you just use the symplectic def2.1 for linear map, so g' preserves the area between two vectors, and I guess the $\Omega$ he defined in equ(2.4) says then g itself preserves the 'area' of manifold, i.e. $\Omega(g(M))=\Omega(M)$ ?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, he shows that at the global level the fact that $g$ is symplectic implies that it preserves the symplectic area of the manifold.